# AWS Aurora read/write synchronization

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a problem with synchronizing Aurora's read and write replicas. Some read queries are executed faster than some write, though write queries come first. The question is: why doesn't aurora use queue between write and read replicas? Is there any way I can fix it in the aws console, not in the code?

Comment: *"Some read queries are executed faster than some write, though write queries come first."*  It is not clear what this statement is intended to mean.

Comment: How do those read queries look like? How do those write queries look like?

Comment: It happened when write and read queries executed at the same time. Let's say a read query selects data that's changing by a write query at the same moment of time. The read query will return an old data. The only solution is pointing the read query to the master.